# Arithmetic Overflow Error in SQL Server 2005 query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a simple query to show me differences in dates between sales order delivery date and purchase order delivery date where there is a link between the two.

I am getting an error when I execute the query below:

```
SELECT T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName], T0.[DocDueDate], T1.[LineNum], T1.[ItemCode], T1.[Dscription], T1.[Quantity], T1.[POTRGNUM],T1.[ShipDate] as 'SO Delivery Date', T1.[U_ShipDetl] as 'PO Delivery Date' 

FROM ORDR T0  INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 

WHERE T0.[DocStatus] ='O' AND T1.[POTRGNUM] IS NOT NULL and (T1.[ShipDate] > T1.[U_ShipDetl])
```

The error message reads:

Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

I notice that one of the fields I am trying to use (t1.u_shipdetl) has been user created so is it possible that is hasn't been created properly?

Thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: one of `ShipDate` and `U_ShipDetl` are not `datetime` data types, and the attempt to convert that one to a datetime value is failing.

Answer (score 0):

One of `ShipDate` and `U_ShipDetl` are not `datetime` data types, and the attempt to convert that one to a datetime value is failing. The *Arithmetic overflow error* suggests it is trying to convert from a numeric type. Perhaps the value is stored as `20170509`? If so, this may work:

```
select
    T0.[DocNum]
  , T0.[CardCode]
  , T0.[CardName]
  , T0.[DocDueDate]
  , T1.[LineNum]
  , T1.[ItemCode]
  , T1.[Dscription]
  , T1.[Quantity]
  , T1.[POTRGNUM]
  , T1.[ShipDate]   as 'SO Delivery Date'
  , T1.[U_ShipDetl] as 'PO Delivery Date'
from ORDR T0
  inner join RDR1 T1 
    on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
where T0.[DocStatus] = 'O' 
  and T1.[POTRGNUM] is not null 
  and T1.[ShipDate] > convert(date,convert(char(8),T1.[U_ShipDetl]))
```

Comment: Hi Zim, THanks for the response.   It results in a new error:

Comment: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Comment: @user3232977 switch to `date` or `datetime2(0-7)` to support dates from `0001-01-01` to `9999-12-31`